# Use an installed python library (from github) in Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, package, spyder

I've installed a python library (https://github.com/rsagroup/pyrsa) on my Mac via the terminal. This package is not part of Anaconda. I would like to work with it in Spyder now, which I just installed via the Anaconda distribution. I have scoured the internet but not been able to figure out how to do this. Would appreciate any tips!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Normally python checks certain locations for modules/packages:

1. current directory
2. the sub-directory called 'site-packages'
3. the path given by the environment variable PYTHONPATH

So therefore, as long as the module' directory is in 1 of the 3 path descriptions given above, and contains a file (empty or not) called '_*init_*.py', python can find it and you can import it.

Note that Anaconda is nothing more than a distribution of python. Which is more or less like a bunch of python packages, the (i)python interpreters and an IDE (spyder/IDLE) bundled together.

More or less the same applies to using Spyder: this is a shell around a python interpeter (actually, I think it is a ipython interpreter, but I'm not sure, since I don't use Spyder). Therefore whether you use Spyder, PyCharm, IDLE or whatever should not impact the directories that python checks for modules/packages.

Summarizing: the package locations **any** python interpreter checks are always the same. This is not linked to whether you use python shipped via Anaconda or the python interpreter preset in your linux/windows operating system.

In your case it might be the best choice between adding the directory in which you've stored the package to the PYTHONPATH environment variable, but opinions may as always differ on the matter.

Comment: Thanks, Joris! That was really helpful for my understanding. I have tried adding a path with PYTHONPATH, but obtain the error "This directory cannot be added to the path." Could this have to do with how I installed pyrsa? It's in iCloud Drive -> Desktop -> env -> lib -> site-packages...